# Azure Automation PowerShell Error "Assembly with same name is already loaded"

Tags: powershell, azure-storage, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I have a script that runs locally but I can't make it run on Azure Automation cloud.

This script records data to the Azure blob and the error is related to the Az module that is the default in Azure Automation.

Here is the script ($Result is object with data):

```
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $Credential
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "xxx" -UseConnectedAccount
$containerName  = "yyy"
$container = Get-AzStorageContainer -Name $containerName -Context $ctx
$date_loaded = (Get-Date -Format "MMddyyyy").ToString()
$content = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Result -join "`r`n")
$container.CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference($date_loaded+".csv").UploadFromByteArray($content,0,$content.Length)
```

Here are the error messages:

```
    The 'Connect-AzAccount' command was found in the module 'Az.Accounts', but the module could not be loaded due to the following error:
[Assembly with same name is already loaded] For more information, run 'Import-Module Az.Accounts'
    
    The term 'New-AzStorageContext' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
    
    The term 'Get-AzStorageContainer' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, 
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I believe it's related to the fact that two Az modules are installed.

[image]

As I am not able to control default modules on a cloud, I don't know how this can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

> The 'Connect-AzAccount' command was found in the module 'Az.Accounts',
> but the module could not be loaded due to the following error:[Assembly with the same name is already loaded] For more information, run 'Import-Module Az.Accounts'

The error message indicates that the **`Az.Accounts`** module is already loaded, but it can't be loaded again. This error occurs when you try to load the same module multiple times in the same session.

To resolve this issue, you can try to remove the module and then import it again.

**Commands:**

```
#Removing module with commands
Remove-Module -Name Az.Accounts
Remove-module -Name Az.Storage

#importing commands
Import-Module Az.Accounts
Import-Module Az.Storage
```

To check the modules are imported you can use the below commands:

**Commands:**

```
#To check the modules:
Get-Module -Name Az.Accounts -ListAvailable
Get-Module -Name Az.Storage -ListAvailable
```

**Output:**

[image]

You can also update the Azure modules in your Automation account by following this [MS-Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-update-azure-modules).

Once the modules are imported, you can use the below script to upload the data in azure blob storage.

**Commands:**

```
    $Appid = "Your app client id"
    $PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "<Your app secret>" -AsPlainText -Force
    $tenant = "Your tenant id "
    $Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $Appid,$PWord
        # $Credential = Get-Credential
    Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant $tenant -ServicePrincipal -Subscription "your subscription ID"
    $ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "storage account name" -UseConnectedAccount
    $containerName  = "container name"
    $container = Get-AzStorageContainer -Name $containerName -Context $ctx
    $date_loaded = (Get-Date -Format "MMddyyyy").ToString()
    $content = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Result -join "`r`n")
    $container.CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference($date_loaded+".csv").UploadFromByteArray($content,0,$content.Length)
```

**Output:**

[image]

And also make sure you have **`Storage-blob-contributor`** role to do this operation.

**Portal:**

[image]

Comment: Hello @Venkatesan,

Could you clarify how can I remove default modules from the Azure Automation cloud?
In the UI this option is greyed out.

I linked the Azure Automation with VS Code and got an error there:
"No modules were removed. Verify that the specification of modules to remove is correct and those modules exist in the runspace."

Comment: At the same time command "Get-Module -Name Az.Accounts -ListAvailable" works ok.

Comment: Try this command `Remove-Module Az -Force` or try with new azure automation account.

Comment: My account has Owner and Contributor access.
Sorry, what account do you suggest using?
-Force doesn't work either, unfortunately. :-(

Comment: Have you tried with another automation account? in portal.

Comment: Yes, it works on another account.